# Android M fingerprint scanner on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, fingerprint

I want to ask how should I test my fingerprint authentication on Android Emulator?

I was trying to use

***adb -e emu finger touch [finger_id]***

referred from [link here](http://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/introducing-androids-fingerprint-api) but it seems to be not working with my Emulator.

My Emulator is Targeting API 23, Android 6.0, x86_64.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a way for a person who does not want to install dev tools to test the fingerprint sensor on Android devices? I just want to test my fingerprint, but apparently Google provides no way to do this other than repeatedly locking your phone. It's extremely frustrating.

Answer (score 119):

You can do it from Emulator itself

**Go to Settings -> Security--> Set a device lock methos-->Create a pattern**

[image]

**Then click on FingerPrint to register some fingerprints**

[image]

Now You can use fingerprints from emulator settings as shown in pic below

[image]

Comment: using android studio 3.4 , android PIXEL api Q emulator . But it always forgot fingerprint after reboot . I have to set fingerprint every time i reboots the emulator

Comment: It should be noted that if you are trying out a module such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-biometrics `isSensorAvailable()` will say the sensor is unavailable until you setup fingerprints as described above.

Comment: the fingerprint addition must be done via the extended control panel; just a note.

Answer (score 15):

Hi you have to connect to Telnet even if you're using Mac:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 5554
```

then enter the cmd to authenticate

```
auth yourtoken
```

your authentication token is in this file '*/Users/yourname/.emulator_console_auth_token*'

then you have to register the finger print before to use the command. So go in Settings -> Security -> Fingerprint -> Add fingerprint and launch the command on terminal

```
finger touch 1
```

Now your fingerprint with ID 1 is enrolled and you can use it to authenticate

Answer (score 8):

Adding to above answer of "br00"

If you are using Windows then please do below steps.

1.) Check if you have telnet installed or not. Simply run "telnet" command in cmd prompt. If it say command not found. Then install telnet using below link:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275(v=ws.10).aspx

For me its simply in Windows 7

```
pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient" in command prompt
```

2.) Run emulator and check its id. Emulator id usually appears in title bar of Emulator. :5554
So id is 5554

3.) Enter below command in cmd prompt

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 5554
```

4.) Add auth token in telnet window:

```
auth "yourtoken String"
```

Usually you will find auth token at below path

> '/Users/yourname/.emulator_console_auth_token'.

Just open the file and copy the token and pass it in above command in telnet window

5.) then you have to register the finger print before to use the command. So go in Settings -> Security -> Fingerprint -> Add fingerprint

Now open your telnet session command window and enter following command:

```
finger touch 1
```

Now your fingerprint with ID 1 is enrolled and you can use it to authenticate

6.) Repeat step 5 if you want to add multiple finger print. But make sure you always add new finger print id. Here is 1 in step 5.

7.) Now when you want to authenticate just use below command in telnet window:

```
finger touch 1
```

That's It

Answer (score 7):

You can do it in the emulator itself

**Go to Settings -> Security--> Set a device lock method-->Create a pattern**

Then click fingerPrint.If you can add fingerprint in the emulator you can use the following command

**./adb -e emu finger touch 1**

Answer (score 3):

Here is a YouTube video describing the fingerprint registration on emulator: [How to Use the Fingerprint Sensor on the Android Studio Emulator](https://youtu.be/L_Det7hWCLU)

Answer (score 2):

follow these steps:

1. Install Android SDK Tools Revision 24.3, if you have not done so.
2. Enroll a new fingerprint in the emulator by going to **Settings > Security > Fingerprint**, then follow the enrollment instructions.
3. Use an emulator to emulate fingerprint touch events with the following command. Use the same command to emulate fingerprint touch events on the lockscreen or in your app.

> adb -e emu finger touch

On Windows, you may have to run telnet 127.0.0.1  followed by finger touch

Comment: I am using windows so used telnet 127.0.0.1 emulator-5554 finger touch ,    It was giving something telnet [-a][-e escape char][-f log file][-l user][-t term][host [port]], and nothing else happening..

Comment: Didnot working, any other solution, this is provided on Android Developers.

Comment: `adb -e emu finger touch 1`. It doesn't work without finger id.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to go the emulator
2. Then go to the settings, in the settings go to security settings and then choose a lock screen method.
3. after you're done with that, then enroll your fingerprint when required to touch the sensor.
4. click the three dots on the emulator that brings out more settings then navigate to fingerprint and select the fingerprint you want to enroll and click touch sensor then you're done.

The short video below explains it better.
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=XmwrOdoN0Qo&t=213s

Answer (score 0):

It works as follows:

`telnet 127.0.0.1 5554` followed by `finger touch 1` for instance. You can give any random number to test it out.