# Mock FingerprintManager in Android tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-fingerprint-api

Is there a way to simulate or mock [FingerprintManager.authenticate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html#authenticate(android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.CryptoObject,%20android.os.CancellationSignal,%20int,%20android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback,%20android.os.Handler))? I want to write instrumented tests for my fingerprint authenticator.

I'm fine if there's a solution with a restriction that the tests can be run either on an emulator or a device. I use JUnit 4.12.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35335892/6950238) question and answers?

Comment: Try to use `PowerMock`, it is able to mock static methods: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockStatic.

Comment: I often find the use of PowerMock as a test smell or architecture smell. More thoughts from others here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30163045/242582

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest that you don't mock it, in the spirit of [not mocking things you don't own](https://github.com/testdouble/contributing-tests/wiki/Don't-mock-what-you-don't-own). What I might suggest instead (from the above link):

> The prescription implied by "don't mock what you don't own" is to introduce your own shim/wrapper/adapter around it. This effectively cordons off the dependency to a single place in your codebase and contextualizes it in the consistent and easy-to-use style you're trying to promote within your codebase. If there's anything awkward about how one needs to invoke the dependency (maybe a chaining API, multi-step invocation, repetitive default configuration, etc.), it can be swept under the rug into that common adapter.

This feels like an instance where the [humble object pattern](http://xunitpatterns.com/Humble%20Object.html) might be appropriate.