# How to set fingerprint lock screen from adb?

Tags: android, adb, fingerprint, biometrics

I am trying to enroll fingerprint to android emulator with adb command line.

I know I can set PIN with this command:

```
adb shell locksettings set-pin 1111
```

I can enter security settings with this:

```
adb shell am start -a android.settings.SECURITY_SETTINGS
```

I can touch fingerprint to sensor with:

```
adb -e emu finger touch 1
```

But is there way how to enroll fingerprint?
Thank You!!

Comment: This answer explains how to enroll a fingerprint in the Android Emulator:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35335892/android-m-fingerprint-scanner-on-android-emulator

Comment: @MichaelDougan from comments: "So go in Settings -> Security -> Fingerprint -> Add fingerprint" ... I want to do this just with command line .. I don't want to do it manually. That is the point of my question.

Comment: @Pavol did you find a way to do this?

Comment: @Jon nope.. currently I open settings page with command above and then I use Xamarin.UITest with Tap commands.

Answer (score 2):

Here are my steps to enroll a fingerprint on the emulator by **only using adb command** (tested on a x86_64, Google API 28 emulator):

- Set the lock screen passcode to be *1111*

```
$ adb shell locksettings set-pin 1111
```

- Start the **Settings** app

```
$ adb shell am start -a android.settings.SECURITY_SETTINGS
```

- Tap the **Fingerprint** item

```
$ adb shell input tap 274 1469
```

- Tap the **Next** button on the confirm screen

```
$ adb shell input tap 914 1704
```

NOTE: the tap's coordinate was getting on the same emulator by enabling the **Show Touch Location** under the **Developer Options** setting.

- Enter the passcode in the confirmation screen

```
$ adb shell input text 1111 && adb shell input keyevent 66
```

- Execute the following command for at least 3 times to finish the fingerprint enrollment

```
$ adb -e emu finger touch 1
```

- Finally, close the screen

```
$ adb shell input tap 914 1704
```

**Updated**:
To find the location for the click/tap action (e.g. `914 1704`) enable the `Pointer location` in the `Developer Option` as attached image

[image]

Comment: how are you able to know that `914 1704` is the designated for Done/Close buttons? Do you have a reference link for me to check?

Comment: it looks like it's actually the <x,y> location of the setting. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: yes, you are correct, those are the <x,y> of the clicking point.
You can find them easily in the Developer option --> enable Pointer location then when ever you click/move the mouse, the location is shown on the top of the screen.